# If ${\sigma _1} = {\sigma _2} = ....={\sigma _n}$ then $A$ is a scalar multiple of a unitary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let ${\sigma _i}$ is singular value of matrix $A\in{M_n}$ for $i=1,2,...,n$ and ${\sigma _1} = {\sigma _2} = ....={\sigma _n}$.

Why does $A$ is a scalar multiple of a unitary matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A = U \Sigma V^*$ is the SVD decomposition of $A$ and $\Sigma = \sigma I$ (that is, $\sigma_1 = \ldots = \sigma_n = \sigma$) then $A = U (\sigma I) V^* = \sigma UV^*$. The matrix $UV^*$ is unitary as a product of unitary matrices.

Comment: @ levap - Let question inverse.Is it true?

Comment: Do you mean whether the converse is true? Yeah. If $A = \sigma U$ with $U$ unitary then $\sqrt{A^*A} = \sqrt{|\sigma|^2 I} = |\sigma|I$ and so all the singular values of $A$ will be identical and equal to $|\sigma|$.